# Do I need to file W-2 for nanny under age 18?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2

If I hired a 17-year-old nanny for the summer, I know I don't have to withhold Social Security or Medicare taxes due to her age, but do I still need to file a W-2 form with the Social Security Administration, showing her earnings, but no withholdings? If so, how do I make it clear she was exempt from the withholding of those taxes? (Typically, for a nanny, I file a schedule H form also; not a 1099.)

Answer (score 3):

Age is not a relevant factor for the question of filing a W2. See the [IRS publication 926](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p926/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink100086765):

> **Form W-2.**
>
> File a separate 2014 Form W-2, for each household employee
>   to whom you pay either of the following wages during the year.
>
> - Social security and Medicare wages of $1,900 or more.
> - Wages from which you withhold federal income tax.

If she's exempt from FICA and you didn't withhold income tax, they you don't need to file W2. However, I suggest you consult with a licensed tax professional (EA/CPA licensed in your state) to be certain.

Pay attention: the fact that she's 17 doesn't *necessarily* make her exempt:

> **Wages not counted**.
>
> Do not count wages you pay to any of the
>   following individuals as social security or Medicare wages, even if
>   these wages are $1,900 or more during the year.
>
> ...
>
> An employee who is under the age of 18 at any time during the year.
>   *Exception: Count these wages if providing household services is the
>   employee's principal occupation. If the employee is a student,
>   providing household services is not considered to be his or her
>   principal occupation.*

Comment: They have payroll services specifically for baby sitters and nannies. It is costly, but it would save you time and not have to learn about employer responsibilities.